# stack smashing detected in R application after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: r, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

Last night I upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 16.04. Today I cannot create R notebooks in Jupyter. Previously I could work in R in Jupyter.

The first error, that I fixed, was some kind of problem with R's zmq library. The kernel kept halting:

```
[I 14:41:28.584 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rzmq/libs/rzmq.so':
  libzmq.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I downloaded and installed rzmq and this problem went away.

Now I  see this error:

```
[I 14:55:40.860 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 98fbc635-6ba4-4e99-88aa-85e49c6e8e8b
*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R terminated
[I 14:55:43.860 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
[W 14:55:50.897 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 98fbc635-6ba4-4e99-88aa-85e49c6e8e8b
*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R terminated
```

Is there some kind of corruption in the R executable? I tried reinstalling R:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall r-base r-base-dev
```

Didn't change a thing though.

When I run R from the command line it works fine, but then I noticed:

```
jim@main:~/Projects/learning/introduction_to_statistical_learning$ which R
/usr/bin/R
```

Which is a different path from the executable jupyter is using.

Note that jupyter is running through my anaconda install and that I am new to R.

How do I get this to work again?

EDIT:

I found this:

https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/issues/558

Which suggests there are some known issues with conda and gcc. It's not clear how to fix this though.

Comment: So do you have the ZeroMQ libraries and the rzmq package installed? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rzmq/index.html

Comment: I have rzmq intalled and can load that library. I also tried apt-get install libzmq-dev and libzmq3-dev, but neither fix the problem.

Comment: I even tried compiling zmq from source.

Comment: Can you load the library using the Python interface? There may be difference in `.libPaths()` between the two instances of running R.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. I do see when I run R from the shell and call .libPaths() I get this: > .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"

Comment: How do I "load the library using the Python interface"?

Comment: A) You've got three different possible  locations for packages for the shell instance of R.  B) I'm not really sure how you execute R commands from Python in a "notebook". In standard R one would issue the command `require(rzmq)` and I assumed you had that aspect in hand and were just looking for help on debugging your setup. C) Why do you say you "tried" compiling `zmq` from source? Wasn't it successful?

Comment: I can import the zmq library from Python, and Python works fine in jupyter.

Comment: Can you run `.libPaths()` in your notebook calls to an R instance?

Comment: No, because I can't create an R notebook in Jupyter. I get the stack smashing error right away and it crashes. Can't issue a single command.

Comment: Hmmm. Makes me think that something is "left over from a previous session". Running R as a console in interactive mode will create a `.Rdata` file that can hold corrupted calls. The fact that your library locations include both /usr/lib/ and usr/local/lib/ remind me of some of hte confusion that is prevalent among OSX users now that Apple has locked down usr/lib/

Comment: rzmq, IRkernel and IRdisplay are all in /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/. I don't see any duplicates between that directory and /usr/lib/R/library/. The other one is empty.

Comment: I tried ripping everything out and reinstalling but it still doesn't work. I am able to get it to work on my laptop, but I can't figure out what is different between the two machines.

Comment: Is the notebook using a copy of R installed by Anaconda? That might be incompatible with something on your system. If so, try uninstalling R from Anaconda and reinstalling IRkernel on your system-installed R.

Comment: Close! I just got it to work by installing Anaconda's R environment and using that instead of the system installed R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it to work by creating an Anaconda R environment and pointing the Jupyter R kernel at Anaconda's executable. This is a work-a-round but a cleaner setup than previously because I would rather use the Anaconda environment.

https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r